# Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 on iMac 2009 failed to install third party repository

Tags: system-installation, repository, mac

yesterday I tried to install the latest Ubuntu desktop on an old iMac from 2009.

For the most part it worked great. But as the wifi adapter is not seen, I chose to check the option to install third parties repository.

The problem is that the installer failed on this step, most of the installation is done, but I am pretty sure some steps that was planned to be done after that have not been done as the installation stopped there.

I can because the password for the main user must be issued even if I checked the fact that I did not want it.

But also the repositories are not setup, Ubuntu still believe there is a cdrom repository, and there is absolutely no repository files at all.

So I have 2 questions : if I reinstall everything but without this repository,

1 - how can I enable it after the installation ?
2 - what would have used the installer to detect and install things like the driver for the wifi from this repository ?

In the end, I still have a question : the installer failed, and saw it, it prompted me if I wanted to send a report, I did, and it seems to have been sent correctly, is there a place I can see this report ?

Comment: If you filed a bug report, you can view it it on launchpad under the bugs *tab* of your account (*the account you logged into during initial filing of that report*). You also didn't specify which Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop installer you tried (*two ISOs were available for 23.04 Desktop; which did you try?*)  FYI:  I'm not sure what repository you're actually asking about sorry.

Comment: The report have been sent via the installer, I never entered any credentials for that. I installed this iso : https://releases.ubuntu.com/23.04/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso. I will have to download it again to be able to find the right term for this repository.

Comment: During the setup of the installation there are 2 options on the same screen as if I want a Normal or Minimal installation : https://149366088.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/ubuntu-new-installer-page-5.jpg do I want third-party software, and additional media formats. I checked both (the second needs internet to be enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the install problem using the iso for the version 23.04 but with the legacy installer.